# ResizeObserver API doesn't get the updated state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, observer-pattern

I am using `ResizeObserver` to call a function when the screen is resized, but I need to get the updated value of a state within the observer in order to determine some conditions before the function gets invoked.

It's something like this:

```
let [test, setTest] = React.useState(true)

const callFunction = () => {
    console.log('function invoked')
    setTest(false) // => set 'test' to 'false', so 'callFunction' can't be invoked again by the observer
}

const observer = React.useRef(
    new ResizeObserver(entries => {
        console.log(test) // => It always has the initial value (true), so the function is always invoked
        if (test === true) {
            callFunction()
        }
    })
)

React.useEffect(() => {
    const body = document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0]
    observer.current.observe(body)

    return () =>  observer.unobserve(body)      
}, [])
```

Don't worry about the details or why I'm doing this, since my application is way more complex than this example.

I only need to know if is there a way to get the updated value within the observer. I've already spent a considerable time trying to figure this out, but I couldn't yet.

Any thoughts?

Comment: The reason you always get true is every time window is resized, react re renders the component, so the state is set to true again. you can define a variable outside the component and set it inside the callFunction. the better way is to pass the  state as the prop to the component and read it there. also you can pass setState alongside the state itself. but this way you can define the state at global level so the state does not reinitialize every time the component re renders.

Comment: @Ako Thank you for your comment, I did the outside variable thing and I could get by with that. If you want to edit it as an answer I'd accept it. I had already thought about props, but in this case this is not an option.

Comment: @Ako `The reason you always get true is every time window is resized, react re renders the component...`: I figured that, but the point is, isn't that the purpose of states, 'to survive' rerenders? What got me confused is that the new value of the state would be read in any other part of the code, as it should be, even after the page be rerendered, only within the observer the initial value is kept. What am I getting wrong here?

Comment: Actually I was wrong in the comment, I'll post the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you are defining new observer in each re render of the component, Move it inside useEffect will solve the problem. also you must change this `observer.unobserve(body)` to this `observer..current.unobserve(body)`.

I have created this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-surf-dqbq1?file=/src/MyComponent.js) to show you how to do it properly. this way you don't need external variable and you can use states safely.

```
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(false);

  const observer = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    observer.current = new ResizeObserver((entries) => {
      console.log(state);
    });

    const body = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
    observer.current.observe(body);

    return () => observer.current.unobserve(body);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setState(true)}>Click Me</button>
      <div>{state.toString()}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: I'm playing around with this, and it runs continuously, even without resizing. https://codesandbox.io/s/resizeobserver-test-w-react-ref-c6nup

Comment: @KevinAshworth code was missing the dependency array